# Numeric Value out of range for excel vba odbc query to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc

I'm trying to run a query over odbc in MS Excel VBA which selects some data from a MySQL database.
The query stays the same but there is an input parameter that changes.

```
SELECT ips_model_ips_assets.ips_asset_id, 
       ips_assets.name, 
       ips_model_ips_assets.allocation, 
       ips_assets.ips_beta, 
       report_categories.name, 
       ips_assets.eu, 
       ips_assets.uk, 
       ips_assets.us, 
       ips_assets.jp, 
       ips_assets.asia, 
       ips_assets.em, 
       ips_assets.global, 
       ips_assets.other 
FROM   ips_model_ips_assets 
       LEFT JOIN ips_assets 
              ON ips_model_ips_assets.ips_asset_id = ips_assets.id 
       LEFT JOIN report_categories 
              ON ips_assets.report_category_id = report_categories.id 
WHERE  ips_model_ips_assets.ips_model_id = (SELECT ips_model_id 
                                            FROM   clients 
                                            WHERE  id = :id) 
       AND ips_model_ips_assets.rebalance_date = (SELECT Max(rebalance_date) 
                                                  FROM   ips_model_ips_assets 
                                                  WHERE 
               ips_model_id = (SELECT ips_model_id 
                               FROM   clients 
                               WHERE  id = :id))
```

A very strange problem is occuring where for a certain value of `:id` I get the following error:

> [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.32] Numeric value out of range

The query works flawlessly for other `:id`s. Additionally, when I run the problematic query direct in mysql it works fine - it is only in vba that the error occurs. I have checked my db tables and all the data types are correct and there doesn't seem to be anyting that would result in a datatype problem. Here's an example output:

```
| 1    | Cash GBP                       | 0.125  | 0     | Cash      | 0      | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 1     |
| 64   | Winton Ucits                   | 0.0726 | 0.59  | CTA       | 0.285  | 0.095 | 0.421 | 0.032 | 0.075 | 0.092  | 0 | 0     |
| 91   | Bluetrend listed               | 0.0176 | 0     | CTA       | 0      | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 1 | 0     |
| 89   | Schroder UK Dynamic Fund       | 0.0858 | 0.2   | Equity LS | 0      | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
| 8890 | RWC Europe Absolute Alpha Fund | 0.0338 | 0.4   | Equity LS | 1      | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
| 90   | JPMorgan EDLS                  | 0.0555 | 0.4   | Equity LS | 0.657  | 0.343 | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
| 88   | GLG Japan Core Alpha           | 0.0387 | 0.941 | Equity LO | 0      | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
| 66   | iShares MSCI World ETF         | 0.113  | 1     | Equity LO | 0.1575 | 0.095 | 0.534 | 0.09  | 0.05  | 0.0235 | 0 | 0.05  |
| 72   | Blackrock European Long Only   | 0.0283 | 1.008 | Equity LO | 1      | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
| 55   | iShares DJ Euro STOXX 50       | 0.0272 | 1.063 | Equity LO | 1      | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
| 37   | Odey Developed Markets         | 0.0635 | 1.2   | Equity LO | 0.186  | 0.324 | 0.314 | 0.049 | 0.035 | 0      | 0 | 0.092 |
| 134  | iShares S&P 500                | 0.026  | 0.942 | Equity LO | 0      | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
| 8894 | Neptune European Opportunities | 0.0321 | 1.064 | Equity LO | 1      | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0      | 0 | 0     |
```

Edit:

The problem occurs on this line of my VBA code:

```
If Rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then //Rs is the recordset
```

For some reason the driver can't seem to get the recordcount. Running `Rs.GetRows` also fails with the same error. If I inspect the `Rs` in the watch window I can see it contains the query results but there is nothing to indicate anything causing this error. The strangest thing is that it only fails some of the time.

Comment: What is the value of id when it crashes?  Is id a SMALLINT?

Comment: It is 10022, although there are higher `id`s that work fine. It fails when the `ips_model_id` in the join = 20